# How to calculate graph edit distance between two multi-graphs using networkx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

Say I have two graphs G and H:

```py
    G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    G.add_node(0, id = 'a', f = 'none')
    G.add_node(1, id = 'b', f = 'k')
    G.add_edge(0, 1, r = 'bicycle')
    G.add_edge(1, 0, r = 'bicycle_r')
    G.add_edge(1, 0, r = 'bicycle_rr')

    H = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    H.add_node(0, id = 'a', f = 'none')
    H.add_node(1, id = 'b', f = 'k')
    H.add_edge(0, 1, r = 'bicycle')
    H.add_edge(1, 0, r = 'bicycle_r')
```

`networkx` provides us a very simple api to calculate the edit distance between two graphs of the same type, i.e., `nx.graph_edit_distance(G, H, node_match=node_match, edge_match=edge_match)`. Here for `node_match` and `edge_match`, I simply define them as exact match for all labels (i.e., `id` and `f` for nodes, and `r` for edges). This is trivial and not important here since there is no substitution operation between 2 graphs in my example.

The edit distance between G and H is expected to be 1, because G has one more edge between node 1 and 0. However, the answer returned by `nx.graph_edit_distance` is 0. It seems like it just ignores the multi-edges between two graph nodes. I have tried it with simple directed graph (i.e. `nx.DiGraph()`), it works well. But I really don't know how to tell the distance calculator to take the deletion of multi-edge into consideration.

I think something is wrong with `nx.graph_edit_distance` when applying it to multi-graphs. I have tried `nx.is_isomorphic` on multi-graphs. This function returns whether two graphs are isomorphic (i.e., whether the distance is 0), and takes exactly the same input as `nx.graph_edit_distance`. They both have `node_match` and `edge_match`. As suggested by the documentation, the input for `edge_match` should be `G1[u1][v1], G2[u2][v2]`, however, when I check the input to `edge_match` for `nx.graph_edit_distance` and `nx.is_isomorphic`, I found that the input edges for `edge_match` in `nx.graph_edit_distance` doesn't have the shape of edges in multi-graph, while it does have that shape for `edge_match` in `nx.is_isomorphic`. I think this could be a serious bug of networkx.

Edit:
I checked the source code of networkx. Now I am pretty sure it's a bug. The usage of `edge_match` is not consistent with what is claimed in the documentation.

```py
    elif edge_match:
        C[0:m, 0:n] = np.array([1 - int(edge_match(G1.edges[g], G2.edges[h]))
                                for g in pending_g for h in pending_h]
                               ).reshape(m, n)
```

Here is my implementation for `node_match` and `edge_match`:

```py
def node_match(n1, n2):
    if n1['id'] == n2['id'] and n1['f'] == n2['f']:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def edge_match(e1, e2):
    if e1['r'] == e2['r']:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def multi_edge_match(e1, e2):
    if e1.keys() != e2.keys():
        return False
    for k in e1.keys():
        if e1[k]['r'] != e2[k]['r']:
            return False
    return True
```

Note that, based on the documentation, for multi-graphs, `edge_match` should not work, because in multi-graph G[u1][u2] is first indexed by an edge id, so I defined `multi_edge_match`. However,`nx.graph_edit_distance(G, H, node_match, multi_edge_match)` will lead to running error. We can only call `nx.graph_edit_distance(G, H, node_match, edge_match)` and then get unexpected results.
 While for `nx.is_isomorphic`, we can only call `nx.is_isomorphic(G, H, node_match, multi_edge_match)` instead of `nx.is_isomorphic(G, H, node_match, edge_match)`, and this is what I have expected. So I think it's likely that the implementation for `nx.graph_edit_distance` is not correct for multi-graphs. At least, it is not consistent with the documentation, if not incorrect.

Comment: Please include your `node_match` and `edeg_match` functions. I suspect the issue is with your implementation of these functions but it is impossible for us to discount that if you don't include them.

Comment: @spinkus makes sense. I have updated my question with these functions.

Comment: I'm using nx 2.4 on Python 3.7. nx.graph_edit_distance gives 1 with or without the node_match or edge_match which I don't think you need.